# Creating an excel function that pulls a certain amount of random data inputs from a set of data - Based on how many inputs are in that specific set

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, formula

Excel help - Picking a certain amount of random numbers based on how large that data set is.

I have 6 data sets. For example, if there are 300 inputs of data in DataSet1, I would want 2 random data inputs pulled from that set. However, if DataSet2 has 1,400 inputs of data, I would want 5 random data inputs pulled from that set.

I essentially want an increment based random number selector, EX: If data =<300, pull 2 numbers from the set
If data 300=<800, Pull 3 pieces of data from the set.

The amount of data from each set doesn't really matter right now, I just need help setting it up. Thank you!

I was thinking of an If statement but I wasn't sure what to input before the random function

Comment: More exact info about sources of datas and required solution method help the answerers. Pls. read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)